# keeping user logged in on a application for long time

Tags: .net

i have a application, and i want the user to be logged in for long time, i.e cookies will not expire, when ever the customer log in he/she will find logged in on the application,

So my question is, is it going to harm my server, will my server get crash or any other problem,

Answer (score 0):

You need to make asynchronous API calls to your server. Whenever you log in, the server will retain the status of your session (i.e 'logged in' or 'guest session') in the database. So you need to design your application in the following manner:-

1. Whenever you start your application, make an API call to check the user session state.
2. Check the response of the API call.
3. If response is 'guest' or 'unlogged' or something, show the user the login page. Once the user logs-in, the session state changes from 'guest session' to 'logged-in'.
   If not, (i.e session status is 'logged in'), then show the user the main app.
4. Whenever the user logs out, the session state will change from 'logged-in' to 'guest'/'unlogged'.

This way the user can remain logged in for any amount of time. If the user closes the page without logging out and again opens the page, even then there is no need to login again, because whenever you start the app, you are going to check the session state.

There is no question of the server crashing or facing any problem, again this depends on how well you write your code.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It wont cause any problem. Now a days servers are so sophisticated that it can handle 1000's of users without any issue.
Working with cookies is old way of authentication.
There are multiple ways to make user authentication. Simple example is to go with "auth id".
Also I suggest you to use "REST" based services which is more popular and easy to develop.